# Tautological 1-form, identifications in calculation of pullback

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

In Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds, he introduces the (coordinate-free) definition of the tautological $1$-form by doing a pullback calculation. It appears that he is making an identification on the way, though, that I am having a hard time understanding. So I did the calculation from scratch, but I do not know how to relate it to what Lee did.

For a manifold $M$, we have the following data:

$\pi:T^*M\to M:\ (q,\varphi)\mapsto q$

$d\pi_{(q,\varphi)}:T_{(q,\varphi)}(T^*M)\to T_qM;\ (d\pi_{(q,\varphi)}v)(f) =v(f\circ\pi_{(q,\varphi)})$ for smooth real-valued $f$.

$d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi)}:\ T^*_qM\to T^*_{(q,\varphi)}(T^*M);\ d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi)}(\omega_q)(v)=\omega(d\pi_{(q,\varphi)}(v)).$

So, in coordinates, if $\omega_q=\sum a_i(q)dx^i$, where it is understood that $dx^i$ acts on $T_qM$, then

$d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi)}(\omega_q)=\sum a_i\circ \pi(q,\phi) \ d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi)}(dx^i)=\sum a_i(q) \ d(x^i\circ \pi).$

In particular, if $\omega=dx^i$ then $d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi_)}(dx^i)=d(x^i\circ \pi)$, where it is understood that $d(x^i\circ \pi)$ acts on $T_{(q,\phi)}(T^*M).$

Lee has $d\pi^*(dx^i)=dx^i$, so I guess he is making some identification because since the domain and range of $d\pi^*$ are different, this cannot be literally true. I imagine this has to do with a "tautology" but I am not seeing it.

Edit: To verify the correct identification, as prof Lee points out in the comments, and using the notation there, we calculate:

If $v=\alpha^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $v'=\beta^i\frac{\partial}{\partial c^i}\in T_{(q,\varphi)}(T^*M),$ we have  $d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi_)}(dx^i)(v+v')=d(x^i\circ \pi)(v+v')=(v+v')(x^i\circ \pi)=\alpha^i$ and if $v=\alpha^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\in T_qM,$ then $dx^iv=\alpha^i$ as well so $d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi_)}(dx^i)$ acts in the same way on tangent vectors in $T_{(q,\varphi)}(T^*M)$ as $dx^i$ acts on vectors in $T_qM$. Hence, the identification.

Comment: Yes, there is an identification going on here -- I use the notation $x^i$ both for the given coordinates on $M$ and the corresponding natural coordinates on $TM$. See page 67.

Comment: I see. I am trying to relate my calculation $d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi_)}(dx^i)=d(x^i\circ \pi)$ to this. For this, I need to see what the elements in  $T_p(T^*M)$ look like in coordinates. Thank you for taking the trouble to respond. (I have read several of your books and they are wonderful for self-study.)

Comment: The intuition is that a tangent vector in $T_{(q,\phi)}T^\ast M$ is a tangent vector in $T_qM$ together with a $1$-form in $T_q^\ast M$, so it makes sense to just evaluate that one-form on that vector.

Comment: An element of $T^*M$ is a pair $(q,\phi)$ which can be expressed in coordinates as $((x^i(q))_i,(c^i(q))_i)$ where the $c^i$ are coefficients of $dx^i$. Now, using either of the two definitions of the tangent space on a general manifold that Prof. Lee uses in his book (collections of derivations or velocities of curves), applied to  tangent bundle $T^*M$, I want to see what $T_{(q,\phi)}T^*M$ looks like and how my calculation fits into the identification of $(x^i,v^i)\in TM$ with $(x^i)\in M$, if it even does.

Comment: There's no identification between $(x^i,v^i)\in TM$ and $(x^i)\in M$. The identification is that when the notation $x^i$ is used in the context of $TM$, what it really means is $x^i\circ\pi$. If you introduce a different notation such as $\tilde x^i$ for that composition, you should be able to sort everything out.

Comment: @JackLee That is what I thought originally when I first read your chapter on tangent bundles. Just to be clear:  in our case,  we start in $T^*M$ with a (local) chart about $(p,\varphi)$ in coordinates written as $(x^1,\cdots, x^n, c^1,\cdots,c^n)$ where the $c^i$ are the coefficients of the covectors  expressed in terms of $dx^i.$  (Continued below)

Comment: @JackLee Then, repeating this construction in $T^*T^*M$, we now get a chart about $((p,\varphi), \xi) \in U\times \mathbb R^{2n}$ in coordinates written as $(x^1,\cdots, x^n, c^1,\cdots,c^n, a^1,\cdots, a^{2n}).$ So all $\pi^*$ does is "transfer"  $(x^1,\cdots, x^n, c^1,\cdots,c^n)$ from one space to the other. Which is why I got $d\pi^*_{(q,\varphi_)}(dx^i)=d(x^i\circ \pi)$ when I did the formal calculation.

Comment: @Matematleta: You don't need to refer to coordinates on $T^*T^*M$. You're writing down a $1$-form on the total space of $T^*M$, and it's going to be a linear combination of $dx^i$'s and $dc^i$'s, with coefficients that are functions of $(x^1,\dots,x^n,c^1,\dots,c^n)$.

Comment: Yes, I see it now! I know I am not supposed to thank people here for their help but seriously, thank you so much. First time in my experience the actual author of a book I am reading has taken the trouble to provide me feedback. Where I live I have no one to talk math with, so this site (and Amazon) is a real godsend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wrote in the comments seems to have clarified things for the OP. But I want to spell things out a little more carefully for anyone else who's interested.

Yes, there is an identification going on here -- I use the notation $x^i$ both for the given coordinates on $M$ and (some of the) corresponding natural coordinates on $T^*M$.

In somewhat more detail, what's going on is this. For any choice of smooth local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on an open subset $U\subseteq M$, you get natural coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n,\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ on $\pi^{-1}(U)\subseteq T^*M$, defined as follows: any point in $\pi^{-1}(U)$ can be thought of as a pair $(q,\varphi)$, where $q\in U$ and $\varphi\in T^*_q M$. This covector $\varphi$ can be written in coordinates as $\varphi= \sum_i \xi_i dx^i|_q$, and we let $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ be the coordinates of $q$ and take the $2n$ numbers $(x^1,\dots,x^n,\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ to be the coordinates of $(q,\varphi)$.  As explained on page 277 of my smooth manifolds book, these provide smooth local coordinates on $T^*M$. Here is where the implicit identification occurs: when the notation $x^i$ is used in the context of $TM$, what it really means is $x^i\circ \pi$.

Thus if $\tau$ denotes the tautological $1$-form on $T^*M$, a local coordinate expression for $\tau$ is going to be a linear combination of $dx^i$'s and $d\xi_i$'s, with coefficients that are functions of $(x^1,\dots,x^n,\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$. If you unwind the abstract definition of $\tau$ and express it in terms of these coordinates, what you get is $\tau = \sum_i \xi_idx^i$.

If you're being confused by the identifications, it might help to introduce a different notation for the coordinate functions on $T^*M$, such as $\tilde x^i = x^i\circ \pi$.